# Magento 1.9 Default Product Sorting on category pages

Tags: magento-1.9

We are on Magento 1.9.3.9 and have run into a problem with the order of our products on the category pages.

The default display was always set to BEST VALUE or POSITION ORDER and then we determined the order the products would display using in the DISPLAY SETTINGS of the category. But they are now displaying in random order and I have tried everything to fix it.

I have attached a couple of screenshots.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8klD.jpg

Comment: Hi Jaimie, what do you mean by "Random Order"? Which `Product Listing Sort By` did you specify in the category?

Comment: Can you please check my solution?. I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You configure this type and save your category and check.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion, I tried it but no luck.

Comment: @Jamie After this update, can you run reindex command?.